# What is the non-abelian exterior square $G\wedge G$ of general linear group $GL(V)$ or $GL(n, \mathbb{R}?$

Tags: abstract-algebra

We all are familiar with the non-abelian exterior square and I also computed for some finite order group. But I am unable to approach in the case of general linear group $GL(n,\mathbb{R}.$

Comment: This seems to suggest the answer is not known [?]  https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3444841/is-sln-mathbbf-simple-group-and-non-abelian-tensor-square-of-gln-mathb